# Trigger bar/pie graph highlight when hovering over an external element [chart.js / chart js] [AngularJS] [angular-chart.js]

Tags: angularjs, chart.js, angular-chart

I am using angular-chart.js to create a dashboard. Instead of using the built in legend within the canvas I created my own and am using ng-repeat to dynamically create the labels with matching colors.

Now, what I would like to accomplish is this: when an item is hovered in my custom legend it would highlight that item in the graph and vice versa.

I was thinking that perhaps if I can find what the event that is triggering the tooltip event I can manipulate that and create a ng-mousover expression...

is this even possible?

Thanks,
Emad

Answer (score -1):

Not exactly, the same but someone posted an example of hiding / showing line on legend click: https://github.com/jtblin/angular-chart.js/issues/70

In Chart.js 2.x, there is support for an onclick event as well on the legend to something similar: http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#chart-configuration-legend-configuration

Answer (score -1):

```
color: [
  {
    backgroundColor: ['#92d06f', '#73c8b8', '#3bb9ab'],
    borderColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)',
    hoverBackgroundColor: ['#92d06f', '#73c8b8', '#3bb9ab'],
    hoverBorderColor: ['#92d06f', '#73c8b8', '#3bb9ab'],
    hoverBorderWidth: 10,
    hoverRadius: 0
```

}
    ],

It works fine when mouse over on active segment in angular 2